# Iterating over variable name

Tags: python, loops, variables

What I want to do is to create like 10 (or more than 10) variables each containing an int in the name, like `M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8, M9, M10` 
Is there any method I can use in Python to iterate over the int contained in the variable name so that I don't have to call each variable when I want to apply the same function to each of them?

Comment: don't create such variables in the first place! Use a list.

Comment: That is what a *container* is for! E.g. a list, dictionary, set, tuple etc...

Comment: Maybe you need a so-called "array"? :) M[0], M[1], etc.